# Gaussian integration of $Z(h) = \int e^{x.\Gamma x+hx} dx$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I am working on the function defined as:

$$Z(h) = \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}x\Gamma x+hx}, dx$$

where $\Gamma$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, $h$ and $x$ are $n$-component vectors : $x =( x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$.

We define the scalar product 
$$\langle g(x)\rangle =\int g(x) P(x)dx$$ 
where

$$P(x)=\frac{1}{Z(0)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x\Gamma x}.$$

Any ideas on how to show that 
$$\langle x_i,x_j \rangle = \left. \frac{\partial^2 \ln(Z(h))}{\partial h_i \partial h_j} \right|_{h=0} ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean $\Gamma$ is positive definite, then $\Gamma = M^\top M$ so that $$Z(h) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac12 \| M x-M^{-\top} h\|^2+\frac12\|M^{-\top}h\|^2}d^n x= \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{- \frac12\| M M^{-1} y-M^{-\top} h\|+\frac12\|M^{-\top}h\|^2}d^n (M^{-1} y) \\ = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac12 \|  y-M^{-\top} h\|^2+\frac12\|M^{-\top}h\|^2}|\det(M)|^{-1} d^n y= \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{- \frac12\|  y\|^2+\frac12\|M^{-\top}h\|^2}|\det(M)|^{-1} d^n y\\ = |\det(M)|^{-1} \sqrt{\pi/2}^ne^{\frac12\|M^{-\top}h\|^2}= |\det(\Gamma)|^{-1/2}  \sqrt{\pi/2}^ne^{\frac12 h^\top \Gamma^{-1} h}$$

Comment: I agree with your derivation but I fail to see how it's related to the computation of $\langle x_i x_j \rangle$

Comment: $\left. \frac{\partial^2 \ln(Z(h))}{\partial h_i \partial h_j} \right|_{h=0} = ?$

Comment: Well it's equal to $\frac{1}{2} \Gamma^{-1}_{ij}$

Comment: And $\langle x_i,x_j \rangle= $ ?

Comment: To $\frac{1}{Z(0)}\int x_ix_j e^{\frac{1}{2}x.\Gamma x} dx$ so I'm struggling to integrate that.

Comment: It is the derivative with respect to $h$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: Right but the relation I'm looking for include the derivative of $ln(Z)$ that's the problem!

Comment: I agree with that but I'm looking for $\left. \partial_{h_i}\partial_{h_j} ln(Z(h)) \right|_{h=0}$

Comment: $\partial_{h_i} \partial_{h_j} Z(h)|_{h=0} = \int x_ix_j e^{-\frac{1}{2}x.\Gamma x} dx=Z(0)\langle x_i,x_j \rangle$. You know how to compute that since you have $Z(h)= |\det(\Gamma)|^{-1/2}  \sqrt{\pi}^ne^{\frac12 h^\top \Gamma^{-1} h}$. On the other hand again from the last formula you have computed $\left. \frac{\partial^2 \ln(Z(h))}{\partial h_i \partial h_j} \right|_{h=0} = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma^{-1}_{ij}$.

Comment: Oh I understand what I have to do, thank you! But the computation gives $\langle x_i x_j\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left|det(\Gamma)\right|^{-1/2} \pi^{n/2} \Gamma^{-1}_{ij}$ which is not the expected result...

Comment: I think you mean $Z(0)\langle x_i x_j\rangle =\left|det(\Gamma)\right|^{-1/2} \pi^{n/2} \Gamma^{-1}_{ij}$ and there is no $1/2$ factor because there is also $\Gamma^{-1}_{ji}$

Comment: Yes I just got that! Thank you for your help!